# Is there no Label control in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, label-control

I can't seem to find a Label control in Silverlight.  I get compile errors if I put  anywhere in my XAML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TextBlock` is roughly the same as a `Label` from WinForms.

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock(VS.95).aspx):

> The TextBlock control is the primary
>   element for displaying text in
>   Silverlight based applications.
>
> Provides a lightweight control for
>   displaying small amounts of text...

**EDIT**: I just noticed your tag for Silverlight 3.  `Label` should be built into Silverlight 3 so are you sure your not using 2?

You might want to consider a TextBlock depending on how your using it.  Again per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label(VS.95).aspx):

> A Label control displays a caption,
>   required field indicator, and
>   validation error indicator to the
>   user. It is typically used together
>   with an input control, such as a
>   TextBox. If you do not need to display
>   required field or validation
>   indicators, you can use the TextBlock
>   control instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try [this article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/SilverlightLabel12132008105302AM/SilverlightLabel.aspx). Apparently, you need to install the Silverlight Toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the TextBlock...?

Michael