# 'Label' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Controls'

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight

Need some help with a typically vague Visual Studio 2008 error.

Error:

```
Error 3 The type or namespace name 'Label' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Relevant code:

```
internal System.Windows.Controls.Label DescriptionLabel;
```

I believe it's something to do with Silverlight, but i have the SDK for Silverlight 3 installed from here http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/36060.
Using Windows 7 x64 and Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

I am not missing any assembly references in any projects as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you referenced the System.Windows.Controls.Data.Input.dll assembly in your project.

Comment: I have this referenced in the project

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Microsoft have removed `label` or its been renamed in Silverlight 3. I was under the assumption that the project needed Silverlight 3, but in fact it uses Silverlight 2.

Installing **[Silverlight 2 Toolkit March 2009](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/20430)** solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend taking a look here: [Is there no Label control in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429420/is-there-no-label-control-in-silverlight)

Seems that if you're targeting SL2 there is no Label control, and if you're targeting SL3 you need to download the toolkit.

Comment: I have the SL3 toolkit installed. Weird but the error still appears